# Async binding in dynamic form

Tags: angular, forms, asynchronous, binding, angular5

Based on the Angular guide on [creating dynamic forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#dynamic-forms) I've set up a bunch of classes that can create forms on the fly. This works great, but it doesn't actually save much effort over just writing the html if I can't just dynamically base the forms on a model object.

So I created a service that dynamically builds the forms based on the properties in a model object.

The problem- the model object is returned from a web service asynchronously. So Angular blows up when doing its initial binding.

```
<dynamic-form [formConfig]="formConfig"></dynamic-form>
```

I've tried making formConfig a `Promise` or an `Observable` and changing this call to:

```
<dynamic-form [formConfig]="formConfig | async"></dynamic-form>
```

but it is still trying to bind immediately and blowing up because `undefined` is being passed into `<dynamic-form>`.

I believe the problem is that the `async` pipe doesn't seem to work as I'd expect on my custom component.

Any advice?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Where is `formConfig` defined? What does *"blowing up"* mean, exactly?

Comment: Giving a "minimal" example with Angular is near-impossible without copying 15 files. This is why I linked to their article that informs the whole process. "Blowing up" means lots of errors because an `undefined` is being passed to the `dynamic-form`. My question is really more about how asynchrony works with bindings in Angular.

Comment: You could always provide a minimal service-component setup and a link to a Plunkr or something for anyone who wants to actually run it. But with just a template snippet and in the absence of error details it's hard to say precisely what the problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I provided error details. You don't need code to understand the problem as described.

Answer (score -1):

For whatever reason, the `async` pipe doesn't seem to work properly with user-written components. I found that instead, guarding the whole thing with `*ngIf` fixes the problem.

```
<div *ngIf="formConfig | async; let formConfig">
    <dynamic-form [formConfig]="formConfig"></dynamic-form>
</div>
```